# Propensity score matching using R

Tags: r, matching, propensity-scores

I have 50 control subjects and I would like to get 150 treatment subjects (i.e., a 1:3 ratio between the control and treatment groups) using propensity score matching and a few covariates. After performing the matching I would like to get indices of matched subjects (i.e., indices for both control and treatment groups) - this is my main goal.

I would like to do this in R. I see that R has the [Matchit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/index.html) and [Matching](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/index.html) packages. However, I  am not sure what the difference is between the two and which one is more appropriate for my purpose.

I am also not sure about the code and what output I need to be looking at to get indices of the matched control and treatment subjects.

Also, could I use the `match()` command without the outcome (i.e., `Y`) variable? The experiment is not yet complete and thus I do not have the outcome variable. Would it be appropriate to use `match(Y=NULL, Tr=.....)`?

Comment: I know that `Match` in the `Matching` package does not require you to supply a `Y` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at an overview here: http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~estuart/propensityscoresoftware.html

Match package does, as Charlie mentioned, let you exclude the outcome variable and will provide you with matching only then.